# Procesamiento complejo de dos arreglos de diccionarios en python

Tags: python, array

Hola tengo dos objetos en python, el primero:

```
 completos = [
        {
        "id": 83,
        "bloque": "Proyectos",
        "atributo": "fecha_cierre",
        "orden": 1,
        "visible_cv_resumido": true,
        "visible_cv_completo": true,
        "mapeo": "fecha_cierre",
        "administrador": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 84,
        "bloque": "Proyectos",
        "atributo": "id",
        "orden": 1,
        "visible_cv_resumido": true,
        "visible_cv_completo": false,
        "mapeo": "id",
        "administrador": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 85,
        "bloque": "Proyectos",
        "atributo": "fecha_inicio",
        "orden": 1,
        "visible_cv_resumido": true,
        "visible_cv_completo": true,
        "mapeo": "fecha_inicio",
        "administrador": 1
    },
]
```

Y otro arreglo asi:

```
data = [
 {
            "id": 1,
            "fecha_inicio": "2005-02-01",
            "fecha_cierre": "2012-01-01",
            "codigo_proyecto": "",
            "nombre_proyecto": "Diferentes dentro del del Conocimiento Tradicional del Pueblo Saraguro",
            "descripcion": "",
            "tipo_proyecto": 65,
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "fecha_inicio": "2008-01-01",
            "fecha_cierre": "2012-06-30",
            "codigo_proyecto": "PROY_CBCM_0011",
            "nombre_proyecto": "PROSPECCION DE PRINCIPIOS ACTIVOS ANTICANCEROSOS DE LA FLORA DEL SUR DEL ECUADOR.",
            "descripcion": "El cancer constituye una de las principales causas de muerte, se estima que para el 2020 cerca de 13 millones de personas falleceran por esta enfermedad. Por tanto, el cancer constituye un problema de salud mundial y ocupa un lugar de importancia en lo",
            "tipo_proyecto": 65,
        }
]
```

Como puedo hacer que en base al campo `visible_cv_completo` del array completos, si ese campo es true pueda obtener la información por ejemplo `"atributo": "fecha_cierre"` del arreglo data y obtener `"fecha_cierre": "2012-01-01"`  o `"atributo": "fecha_inicio"` y del arreglo data obtener `"fecha_inicio": "2005-02-01"`En el primer arreglo llamado completos tengo en el campo `atributo` lo que deseo obtener del arreglo data. No se como hacerlo. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Como se sabe de qué elemento del segundo array hay que sacar el atributo en cuestión? ¿Sería de todos ellos o solo del que tenga un cierto `id`? ¿Qué id en ese caso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es lo siguiente:

- De la primera lista `completos` sacar la lista de atributos que deberían ser visibles. Según tu ejemplo, esa lista sería `['fecha_cierre', 'fecha_inicio']` pues son los que tienen `True` en la clave `"visible_cv_completo"`
- De la segunda lista `data`, volver a copiar todos los diccionarios que contiene, pero dejando en cada uno de esos diccionarios sólo las claves de la lista antes obtenida (o sea, sólo las claves `"fecha_cierre"` y `"fecha_inicio"`).

Esto puede lograrse con un par de comprensiones de listas.

### Extraer la lista de atributos visibles

```
visibles = [ d["atributo"] for d in completos if d.get("visible_cv_completo") ]
```

Esta es bastante directa: iteramos por la lista `completos` obteniendo un diccionario `d` cada vez, y si en ese diccionario la clave `"visible_cv_completo"` es *truthy*, añadimos al resultado `d["atributo"]`

### Filtrar los diccionarios de la segunda lista

Esta es un poco más complicada:

```
filtrados = [ {atributo: d.get(atributo) for atributo in visibles} for d in data ]
```

Aquí de nuevo iteramos, esta vez por la lista `data`, obteniendo un diccionario `d` en cada iteración. En base a ese diccionario `d` construimos otro, mediante la expresión `{atributo: d.get(atributo) for atributo in visibles}`. Esta otra expresión es una *comprensión de diccionario*, en la que itero por los atributos que hay en la lista `visibles` y para cada atributo obtengo su valor del diccionario `d` que en ese momento se está procesando en el bucle "principal".

Aplicando este código a tu ejemplo (tras editar tu ejemplo  para que sea Python correcto, que no lo es, pues hay que pasar a mayúscula los valores `True` y `False`), sale el siguiente resultado en la lista `filtrados`:

```
[{'fecha_cierre': '2012-01-01', 'fecha_inicio': '2005-02-01'},
 {'fecha_cierre': '2012-06-30', 'fecha_inicio': '2008-01-01'}]
```

Que espero que sea lo que buscabas.

Comment: eso es lo que estaba buscando, muchas gracias!!